# image captioning by LSTM: The right place to inject info from images

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am doing the image captioning using Tensorflow. What bothers me is that how I should structure my whole network.

In one of the original paper [show and tell, 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06647), They "add" an extra LSTM cell at the beginning (the topology is in unrolled version) and pass the image in the LSTM first to kind of implicitly initialize the cell state and hidden state.

On the other hand, many tutorials online, like [this one](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/22_Image_Captioning.ipynb), choose to use image info as initial state in the network directly to initialize the cell state.

It's quite surprising that no ones seems to discuss what the pros and cons are of these two maneuvers.

Did anyone read any paper, discussion on this or do some sort of experiment to figure this out here? Thank you.